# Is there a way to change the "on" listeners in the Node.js net (Sockets) library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm using Node.js's [net library](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) to set up a basic TCP socket connection:

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("socket to me:", data);
    });
}).listen();
```

Is there a way to remove or change the `socket.on("data")` listener, without closing the connection?  I tried the obvious thing:

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("socket to me:", data.toString());
        socket.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log("ouch");
        });
    });
}).listen(10101);
```

When I connect from the client:

```
var client = net.connect({host: "localhost", port: 10101});
client.write("boom!");
```

It prints `socket to me: boom!`, as expected.  But the next write outputs:

```
socket to me: boom!
ouch
```

Is there any way to alter the first listener, or remove it and replace it with a different one?

Comment: If you have named callbacks, you should be able to do a `.removeListener` for the `data` event and add a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that editing the socket's `_events` object directly lets you swap out listeners, even if they're anonymous.  For example:

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("socket to me:", data.toString());
        socket._events.data = function (data) {
            console.log("ouch");
        };
    });
}).listen(10101);
```

And then in the client:

```
var client = net.connect({host: "localhost", port: 10101});
client.write("boom!");
client.write("boom!");
```

Outputs:

```
socket to me: boom!
ouch
```

Just thought I'd share this here, in case it's useful to anyone else!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a conditional inside the listener?

```
var firstExecution = true;

net.createServer(function (socket) {

    socket.on("data", function (data) {

        if (firstExecution) {
            console.log("socket to me:", data.toString());
            firstExecution = false;
        }
        else {
            console.log("ouch");
        }
    });
}).listen(10101);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now!  I'm sending JSON through the socket, so I added a label to it, and have a giant, increasingly unwieldy switch inside the listener.  What prompted me to ask this question is wanting to move this logic around a bit.  I can confirm that a big fat conditional does work fine, though :)